# Whenever the tab URL changes, the code written in the content script after $(document).ready(function(){}) doesn't get injected. How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I've created a chrome extension for a website which uses ajax calls for web page navigation, so I had to reload the page each time for the script to get injected. To avoid this , I'm using something like this:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId,changeInfo,tab) {
    if(changeInfo.url){
     console.log("tab url changed");
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"});
         chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "payload.js"});
        }

});
```

So whenever I navigate between pages in the website, "tab url changed" gets printed in the console.This is a snippet of what I have in my payload.js:

```
     console.log("ready");
     $(document).ready(function() {
     var button = document.getElementsByClassName("recommend u-flexColumn u-marginBottom10 u-width60")[0];
     if (button) {
      console.log("element is ready");
     }
     });
```

So whenever I click on links within the website, "ready" always gets printed. But "element is ready" doesn't always print, because $(document).ready(function() gets executed only on page reload. How can I get the code after document ready to execute each time also, without having to reload the page each time? I have also added "run_at": "document_end" in manifest.json.

Comment: Don't use `ready` at all. Your code already runs after the document is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) is incorrect.

You should pass `tabId` as first param:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.url) {
      console.log("tab url changed");
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"});
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "payload.js"});
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't fix the problem.